# Tags: heap vs heap-memory

Tags: support, stack-overflow, synonym-request

I stumbled across the [heap](/questions/tagged/heap) and [heap-memory](/questions/tagged/heap-memory) tags.

They are very similar, both descriptions indicate that the tag is about heap memory. Although the [heap-memory tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/heap-memory/info) is far more extensive.

When looking at the questions tagged with [heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heap) and [heap-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heap-memory), both tags are (most of the time) randomly used and often both.

<del>Therefore, I propose that we use [heap-memory](/questions/tagged/heap-memory) (it is more clear that we are talking about a type of memory and *not* some sort of sorting algorithm) and make [heap](/questions/tagged/heap) a synonym of it.</del>

**Update**: As [Mac noticed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158659/141775) [heap](/questions/tagged/heap) is not a correct synonym for [heap-data](/questions/tagged/heap-data)! [heap](/questions/tagged/heap) is ambiguous (could use used for at least three different subjects). So, it needs to be replaced.

[heap-data-structure](/questions/tagged/heap-data-structure) seemed a bit long, so [Daniel Fischer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/177145/daniel-fischer) came with [heap-structure](/questions/tagged/heap-structure).

The *updated proposal* is:

- use [heap-memory](/questions/tagged/heap-memory) it is more clear that we are talking about a type of memory and *not* some sort of sorting algorithm or data structure.
- use [heap-structure](/questions/tagged/heap-structure) (instead of [heap](/questions/tagged/heap)) for question about heap data structures. It will need a new tag wiki, the one of [heap](/questions/tagged/heap) is describing heap-memory.
- continue to use [heapsort](/questions/tagged/heapsort) for questions about the sorting algorithm
- Forbid the use of [heap](/questions/tagged/heap) as it is ambiguous.

Answer (score 7):

The current tag wiki for [heap](/questions/tagged/heap) implies it is indeed a synonym of [heap-memory](/questions/tagged/heap-memory). However, a `heap` also refers to a particular [data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) which may or may not be related to memory allocation:

> A heap data structure should not be confused with the heap which is a
>   common name for dynamically allocated memory. The term was originally
>   used only for the data structure.

As such, IMHO the correct course of action would be to retag questions to [heap-memory](/questions/tagged/heap-memory) where appropriate, but not turn [heap](/questions/tagged/heap) into a synonym. Then, if there's any questions that are related to the data structure, an edit to the [heap](/questions/tagged/heap) tag wiki (or creation of, say, a [heap-data-structure](/questions/tagged/heap-data-structure) tag) would be in order.

Comment: Hm... it might be better to rename [tag:heap] to [tag:heap-data] (or something similar) and forbid letting users use [tag:heap] afterwards..?

Comment: @Veger: I was just considering that myself. I was just going to see if I could find a precedent before making a suggestion. Something like [tag:heap-data-structure] is probably the most accurate, if a bit of a mouthful.

Comment: Would [tag:heap-structure] be bearable?

Comment: @DanielFischer: sounds good to me. Personally, I'd rather just plain old [tag:heap], but I realise that's just asking for trouble due to the ambiguity. My only objection to [tag:heap-data] was that is sounds like it should apply to data residing on the heap, rather than to a data structure - I think your suggestion resolves that just fine, and shorter is always better. Good call. :)

Comment: Agreed. [tag:heap] is nicer, but unfortunately leads to the ambiguity.